# Trying to add an event info page to WordPress page but there is no insert button

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I have CiviCRM version 5.7.0 installed on WordPress 4.9.8. WordPress is using a child theme of Divi 3.17.1.

The website is transitioning from Drupal to WordPress so this install is in a sandbox which is setup as a sub-domain (not on the same server as the live Drupal site). Resource URLs appear to be right.

I get a CiviCRM button on my WP pages which takes me to the Insert CiviCRM Content where I can select "Event Page" and then the appropriate event. However I do not see an insert button on the Insert CiviCRM Content page. Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to:

[image: civicrm screenshot]

Any thoughts?

I have deactivated all of the plugins and have changed the theme to Twenty Seventeen with no results. I also have no JS errors in the console. I'm stuck as to what to try next.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble visualizing this.  Could you possibly edit your question to add a screenshot?

Comment: @Jon I have a feeling that the Shortcode popup isn't, ahem, popping up and is being rendered as a separate admin page at `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fshortcode&reset=1`. 

@IMCnate it sounds like Divi is interfering with the Javascript responsible for intercepting clicks on the Shortcode button - you'll need to check your browser's Console for errors and (most likely as it's a non-free theme) approach Divi for a fix.

Comment: @Jon G I have edited my question to include a screenshot. I can choose an event but there isn't a way to insert it onto a page (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @Christian Wach I have deactivated all plugins except for CiviCRM and have switched the theme to Twenty Seventeen and I still get the same thing. I have inspected the Console and no errors/warnings appear.

Comment: how does what you are seeing compare to https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org or doesn't the demo site let you test for the above?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion unfortunately the demo site doesn't give you access to pages/posts so I cannot demo this. According to the CiviCRM documentation, I should be able to click on the CiviCRM icon on a page/post and insert in Civi shortcodes to display, in this case, an event info page. Instead of being able to insert in the shortcode, I am stuck at the above screenshot.

Comment: I've just checked on our test wordpress site - (Running 5.7.2) and clicking on the civicrm button launches in a pop up (as referenced by Jon G  above). I managed to duplicate what's happening for you by coping the link location and loading in a new window - which indeed causes problems - there is no insert/cancel button! When you reference there being no errors in console - do you mean on the "new post page" - before you click on the civicrm button?

Comment: @IMCnate As I suspected your popup is rendered as a separate admin page. Does the page source of your "Edit Page" screen include the file `wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js`?

Comment: @Luke Stewart there are no JS errors in the console when I inspect the page (both backend and frontend). I have also checked for JS errors on the admin page I'm getting rather than the popup and on the CiviCRM dashboard. No errors.

Comment: @Christian Wach I do see that JS file in the page source for the "edit page" I'm trying to add the CiviEvent to. The same file is also present in the page source for the admin page the shortcode button is taking me to.

Comment: @IMCnate I'm stumped then - the Javascript should be preventing the admin page from loading and should load it in a popup instead. Not sure what to suggest next.

Comment: @Christian Wach thanks for your help. I installed CiviCRM on a different sandbox and everything is working as it should. The only difference in the two installations of Civi is that the one that I'm having issues with is being transferred from Drupal to WordPress and the one that is working is a fresh install. I'm completely stumped as well. I'm going to start a comparison of the two installations and see if I notice anything.